# Mapping json complex object to plain object

Tags: c#, json, mapping, automapper

What I am doing is converting JSON that I get from YAHOO weather to my `YahooWeatherModel` class.

My json object after deserialisation (I use json.net) looks like this:

```
public class WeatherObject
{
    public Location location { get; set; }
    public List<Forecasts> forecasts { get; set; }
}

public class Location
{
    public string country { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; }
}

public class Forecasts
{
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public string Low { get; set; }
    public string High { get; set; }
    public int Text { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

what I need is to convert this object to something like this:

```
public class YahooWeatherModel
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Day { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int Low { get; set; }
    public int High { get; set; }
    public int Text { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
}
```

I use Automapper for mapping. I understand how to create map for location class part in my WeatherObject:

```
var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => cfg
    .CreateMap<WeatherObject, YahooWeatherModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Country, opt => opt.MapFrom(map => map.location.country))
    .ForMember(dest => dest.City, opt => opt.MapFrom(map => map.location.city))
```

But how can I convert List to plain data without list? 
For example in location I have country=latvia, city=riga and in forecast I have 7 items for each week day with other weather data.

What I want to get is list of YahooWeatherModel with 7 elements with country, city, day, low, high... etc info

Comment: I am not sure how are you going to flatten `List<T1>` to `T2`, you can do smth like `T2 = List<T1>.First()` of course but the question is what exactly are you trying to achieve ? What is the expected end result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using LINQ:

```
public void Convert(WeatherObject weatherObject)
{
    IEnumerable<YahooWeatherModel> models = from forecast in weatherObject.forecasts
        select new YahooWeatherModel
        {
            Country = weatherObject.location.country,
            City = weatherObject.location.city,
            Code = forecast.Code,
            Date = System.Convert.ToDateTime(forecast.Date),
            Day = forecast.Day,
            High = System.Convert.ToInt32(forecast.High),
            Low = System.Convert.ToInt32(forecast.Low),
            Text = forecast.Text
        };
}
```